# Get user's gender using the old Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

As you know facebook has moved to api 2.4, and now I can't get the user's gender with my previous code.

```
    $f1 = new Fb_ypbox();
    $user_data = $f1->getUserData();
    $fb_user_id        = $user_data['id'];
            $name = $user_data['name];
$gender = $user_data['gender'];
$birthday = $user_data['birthday'];
```

Now this code only gets the user id & the usre name & his profile picture.
Not the gender or his birth date (although I have the extended permission of user_birthday).

Is there any chance to update my code or any other code to get the user's public info (gender for example) which doesn't request any extended permissions?

I just know that now it's not just making the GET request for "/me", but I also should add the "?fields=gender" addition.. I just can't manage to add it to my current sdk code.

I have read Facebook's API documentation couple of times and I can't figure it out..

Thanks :)

Comment: Correct you need to add fields=gender

Comment: Yes, I already know that. But I have no idea where should I add this in my php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to supply a more detailed description like the version of that "Fb_ypbox" class you are using. Probably there is a new version available that deals with the declarative fields changes in the 2.4 API already.

Since you did not supply these information we can only make a guess:

Search for "//graph.facebook.com/me?" in all class files and add the fields=name,gender,...

Comment: Thanks alot lars.shwarz! I don't know how I didn't think about it before asking here.. thanks again, it works now.